# Evaluating a sequence of conditions and stopping when condition met

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

This is just a "best practise" question...

I have a function that takes an input string and then has to change it based on the content but once a particular condition is met, then all further processing stops.

At the moment, I use a "while(true)" loop and then "break" when I've got what I want, below is pseudo-code..

```
string Input = "xyz";
string Output = string.Empty;
while (true)
{
    if (Input.StartsWith("x"))
    {
        Output = "string starts with an X";
        break;
    }

    if (Input.Contains("y"))
    {
        Output = "string has a 'y' in it";
        break;
    }

    if (Input.IndexOf("z") == 2)
    {
        Output = "string has a 'z' as the 3rd character";
        break;
    }

    Output = "string does not match any conditions";
    break;
}
```

Is there a more "purist" way to acheive the above?

Thanks

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: In the good old days when I used to code in CA-Clipper, there was the code construct of BEGIN SEQUENCE....END SEQUENCE and you could "break" in between...

http://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/reference/c53g01c/ngfc7b7.html

Answer (score 4):

You should use standard `if-ifelse-else` here. It's much more common and readable for your case.

```
string Input = "xyz";
string Output = string.Empty;

if (Input.StartsWith("x"))
{
    Output = "string starts with an X";
}
else if (Input.Contains("y"))
{
    Output = "string has a 'y' in it";
}
else if (Input.IndexOf("z") == 2)
{
    Output = "string has a 'z' as the 3rd character";
}
else
{
    Output = "string does not match any conditions";
}
```

***Update***

Second version, using LINQ. You can create `List` of condition function and desired output and then use `FirstOrDefault` to get first matching condition.

```
string Input = "xyz";
string Output = string.Empty;

var conditionList = new List<Tuple<Func<string, bool>, string>>();
conditionList.Add(Tuple.Create<Func<string, bool>, string>((string x) => x.StartsWith("x"), "string starts with x"));
conditionList.Add(Tuple.Create<Func<string, bool>, string>((string x) => x.Contains("y"), "string has a 'y' in it"));
conditionList.Add(Tuple.Create<Func<string, bool>, string>((string x) => x.IndexOf("z") == 2, "string has a 'z' as the 3rd character"));

var firstMatch = conditionList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1(Input));
Output = firstMatch != null ? firstMatch.Item2 : "string does not match any conditions";
```

Comment: I accept what you are saying but the example above is just a simple explanation. The actual process I am doing has a significant amount of them

Answer (score 1):

As you have said this is just a trivial example of a bigger problem I would probably do it something like this (of course this is overkill for a small example, but it scales very well):

```
public interface ICondition
{
    bool IsMatch(string input);
    string GetMessage();
}

public class StartsWithTest : ICondition
{
    public bool IsMatch(string input)
    {
        return input.StartsWith("x");
    }   

    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "string starts with an X";
    }
}


public class TestInput
{

    private readonly IList<ICondition> _conditions;

    public TestInput()
    {
        _conditions = new List<ICondition>();

        _conditions.Add(new StartsWithTest());
        //etc etc
    }

    public string Test(string input)
    {
        var match = _conditions.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsMatch(input));

        if (match != null)
            return match.GetMessage();
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `if else if..` should suffice. The way you did it, if you refactor your code and forget the last `break;` you may face bigger problems.

Comment: I accept what you are saying but the example above is just a simple explanation.

The actual process I am doing has a significant amount of them.

Comment: You could create a `Disctionary<Func<string, bool>, string>` that for each key (a function ie: `(input)=>input.Contains("y")`) we affect the appropriate output string ( `"string has a 'y' in it"` ) use LINQ to read from the dictionary and return the appropriate output string.